# Function typing React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image]
Can someone help me please, I keep getting this error `"TS2345: Argument of type void is not assignable to parameter of type  Quote | (() => Quote)"` but I'm trying to initialize the value of the state with a function that fetches and returns data.

I've tried to set the function type to `any`, but that did not work.

Comment: Even setting aside the typescript stuff, it's not possible to synchronously initialize a state to a value that doesn't exist yet. Your `useEffect` look correct though, so i'd recommend you initilize the state with `null` or another placeholder to indicate the data is not yet loaded. `const [quote, setQuote] = useState<Quote | null>(null)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: See also https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#fetching-data-with-effects

Answer (score 0):

The function type *void* means that when you call the function, it will **not return** any value. This basically means that the function will do some operations but not give any values back.

To give a value to your state, your value's type must match the state's given types, which in this case means your `getQuote()` function must return a `Quote`.

Also `fetch()` will return a Promise and cannot assign a value which is not there yet to a state. So you should first set it up as `useState<Quote | null>(null)` and after the fetch completes assign the value to the state.